# Code not compilable after Checkstyle integration in my Project

Tags: android, checkstyle

I integrated [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) in my android project. After integration I am getting following error:

> Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Task not found
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForProdDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   java process with main class
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments
>   {--input
>   /Users/BharatVerma/office_stuff/vadaPow/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/prod/debug/142.jar
>   --output /Users/BharatVerma/office_stuff/vadaPow/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/prod/debug/170.jar

Below are the steps I followed:

Apply Plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

Add Dependency:

```
debugCompile "com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:${v.checkStyle}" //v.checkStyle = 8.5
```

Create a task:

```
task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    source 'src'
    classpath = files()
}
```

This code was not giving any error on the day I integrated this. But today when I compiled it, I found it not working.

Comment: Don't add the dependency, and don't add the task. The `apply plugin` already does all of that. Instead, put your config in a `checkstyle { ... }` section.

Comment: And try not to set `classpath` either.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Thank you sir. I tried steps you mentioned but I am unable to run `./gradlew check` or `./gradlew checkstyleMain`. Looks like tasks are not being created by these steps.